# Date is possibly null

Tags: reactjs, date, state, push, recoiljs

i made a function that will take the date and then change it to a string, however typescript says that it is possibly null, how would i make typescript happy.

i am using MUI date picker and recoil, i want to push the date to a global state to use for later

```
 // Start Date

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useRecoilState(StartDateState);

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleChange = (newValue: Date | null) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    setStartDate(newValue.toString());
  };
```

error above = (parameter) newValue: Date | null Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

My Atom is

```
export const StartDateState = atom({
  key: "StartDateState",
  default: "",
});
```

My ui that i want to show it in is

```
 const date = useRecoilValue(StartDateState);

  Start Date : {date ? date : "No Start Date"}
```

So in total i want to push the date to a global state and use it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `Date | null`

it should be `Date` only

because you can not show the null inside of JSX

Comment: i Did however i then get another error for the date picker from MUI on the ```onChange={handleChange}``` saying ```Type '(newValue: Date) => void' is not assignable to type '(date: Date | null, keyboardInputValue?: string | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'newValue' and 'date' are incompatible.
    Type 'Date | null' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Date'.ts(2322)```

Answer (score 0):

The answer i found that worked is this

```
 const handleChange = (newValue: Date | null) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    setStartDate(newValue ? newValue.toString() : "");
  };
```

and my atom to be

```
import { atom } from "recoil";


export const StartDateState = atom({
  key: "StartDateState",
  default: "",
});
```